# Assigning a new IP to my domain

Tags: nameserver, domain-name-system

I am facing a terrible slowdown & inability to access to my website from time to time after changing it's IP. Below is what exactly happened and I would be glad if an expert can tell me what might have gone wrong.

I have a dedicated server with cpanel. 
I was using a shared IP for the website till yesterday which was primary NS's IP. (Which also has 20 more websites under it)
I had to use SSL Certificate on this website, and therefore I changed it's IP address.
And, instead of creating another IP (I have been given access to 30 IP's by datacenter), I chose to assign secondary NS's IP to the website.
And then, I went to domain provider and changed the order of NS's in update nameservers section (put ns2 to first, ns2 to second)

Shortly, I had:
xx.xx.xxx.20 - ns1.maindomain.com
xx.xx.xxx.21 - ns2.maindomain.com

on my server. Website is now pointing to xx.xx.xx.21 but occasionally cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi page pops up with error.
Is it something to do with DNS propagation? (It has been 12 hours) Last time I tried an ip change, it didn't take this long.

In which step might I have done something wrong that can cause the slowdown?
For the future cases, could it be simpler if I just set a new IP and assign the website to it without touching to domain NS setup and secondary NS? :)

Appreciate your help,

Comment: "pops up with error" and that error would be... ?

Comment: This is the error: If you are the web site owner, it is possible you have reached this page because:

The IP address has changed.
There has been a server misconfiguration.
The site may have been moved to a different server.
If you are the owner of this website and were not expecting to see this page, please contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem!
The problem to the slowdown was not due to Mysql. After changing the IP address, I also changed IP address for the mysql connection. Although I allowed new IP address (secondary ns) to connect to database (added it to the list of ip's that can access remotely from cpanel) there was a slowdown.
Problem is solved, but I am curious why did i have problems accessing mysql from a different ip (although that ip was given access to it)